# jQuery 1.3.2 -using .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, click, jquery-events

I am using a program that requires jQuery 1.3.2 and haven't been able to get the `.click()` function to work, but I am able to get function like `.hover()` to work.

This works fine:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#alert_button").hover(function(){
            alert("The monitor has been notified - please wait in your room and they will be by shortly");
        });
    });
```

But this does not:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#alert_button").click(function(){
            alert("The monitor has been notified - please wait in your room and they will be by shortly");
        });
    });
```

Did 1.3.2 not support `.click()`? And if not was there an alternative event handler to use?

Comment: Can you post a live demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: `.click` definitely existed in 1.3.2. Are you sure `.hover -> .click` is the only difference?

Comment: Perhaps there is another `click` handler bound to the same element that stops the propagation of the event to your handler..

Comment: Seems good to me. DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8yxTy/ Somewhere else is the problem. Post more code

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli that must be it - I'll go try to find it in one of the extension files

Comment: Is `$("#alert_button")` created dynamically?

Comment: @user2512696 try `$("#alert_button").unbind('click').click(/*your function*/);` to see if indeed that is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.click()` *will* work in any case... [demo](http://jsbin.com/EPACIveL/1/edit)

Rather, `.hover()` will not work in **Chrome** for `action` elements like `<button>` [demo](http://jsbin.com/EPACIveL/2/edit)

If you're fine with the above mentioned than your error lies somewhere else,
open Firebug or any Developer console and see if you have some other JS errors.

Comment: hover isn't the method he's having problems with.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - Thanks I found another click handler in one of the extension files that was on the same button!

Comment: @user2512696 you're welcome, glad you found the issue

Answer (score 0):

working fine, your code may be facing some conflicts. Kindly check your browser console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Update your jQuery to 2.03 and change .click to .on('click', function...

Your version is very old, and have many deprecated code.